# Problem with browser flash plugin

Tags: flash

YouTube video does not work properly (see image). How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Salam o alikum =)

this may help you :

How to install or fix your flash installation in Linux Mint

1. Open Synaptic ; under administration menu
2. Search 'Adobe'
3. find, scroll down to, Adobe Flash Player plugin installer, which is titled 'flashplugin-installer'
4. right click and click 'mark for installation', or double click
5. click 'apply' in the toolbar

if it is already installed, then right click and click re-install

if that doesn't fix it, then check to see what other 'flash' files are installed; scroll down

only 'mint-flashplugin-11' should be installed, uninstall everything else
THEN
re-install 'flashplugin-installer'

does this work for you? y/n

good luck

Comment: Thank you my friend, but the problem still exists does not work any flash file

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest switching to HTML5 player as this is one of the easiest ways to solve your problem. Open a youtube page, navigate to footer and click Try Something New, it will redirect you to this page:

https://www.youtube.com/testtube

Once there, click on Try It Out under HTML5 player and try to view the video you had problems with.

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work with me